# Override TriStateCheckboxes behavior in RadTreeView

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik, radtreeview

The default behavior of RTV's TriStateCheckboxes upon checking is to check all of the node's children and set ancestors to indeterminate. I would like to override this behavior to only set ancestors to indeterminate, without checking children.

So far I've tried to set CheckChildNodes to false and to cancel the ClientNodeChecking event to set the node and ancestor values myself, but setting node values programmatically invokes the default behavior anyway.

Is there any way I can get past this?

Comment: Couldn't find a very good solution to this, I eventually just created my own tristate checkbox implementation using checkbox icons.

Comment: I've previously attached to a couple of client side events so I could get access to the checkbox element and the indeterminate attribute, post render. I'm not going to propose it as an answer because it was a real pain.